# jvectormap : How can i get rid of the name of region that appears when i click on it

Tags: jvectormap

I have tried to make the font-size 0 but I still see the name
Does anyone have an idea?
Thanks

```
regionLabelStyle: {
              initial: {
                    'font-family': 'Verdana',
                    'font-size': '0',
                    'font-weight': 'bold',
                    cursor: 'default',
                    fill: 'black'
                  },
                  hover: {
                    cursor: 'pointer'
                  }
                }
```

Comment: When you click on it or when you hover over it?

Comment: It happens when i click on it, and i have tried to set the font-size to 0 for the states selected, hover and selectedHover, to no avail

Answer (score 0):

```
markerLabelStyle: {
initial: {
    'font-size': '8',
}
```

Specify your font-size inside *markerLabelStyle*.